# Not able to read hive partitions using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql

I am having a partitioned hive orc table which i am trying to read in spark using this query

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from test.puid_tuid where date = '20170316'").show
```

but getting this error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   hdfs://localhost:8020/hive/warehouse/test.db/puid_tuid/date=20170316
>   does not exist.   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$DirListingIterator.(DistributedFileSystem.java:948)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$DirListingIterator.(DistributedFileSystem.java:927)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:872)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$19.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:868)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:886)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1696)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims.listLocatedStatus(Hadoop23Shims.java:667)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.getAcidState(AcidUtils.java:361)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:634)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$FileGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:620)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

So i checked this path in my hdfs, which is not there.

Then after i executed same query in hive which is ending with zero records.

I also listed all hive partitions and it contains same partitions.

Is there any way in spark, using which we can ignore all the partitions for which file is not available in hdfs?

Comment: Can you post list of file in hdfs://localhost:8020/hive/warehouse/test.db/puid_tuid/

Comment: I am not sure why you need list of files. by the way there are folders in this directory as it is a partitioned table.

Comment: Well it could be an error because it is case sensitive here. Also, you may not have added that partition to the metadata. Do, alter add partition to be sure.

Comment: Have you ruled out that there is no problem with case here - like @morfious902002 said? Eitherway, a better approach would be to address the logic such that a situation like that doesn't occur. It seems to me that the underlying hdfs folders were removed outside of hive's control. So, the metastore still has information about the partitions which existed at some point, but the content on hdfs got deleted. You can simply alter table and drop all such partitions which no longer existed (using hive or even sqlContext), and then you wouldn't see that error anymore.